# Metamask transaction pending?

Tags: blockchain, metamask

Transaction send through metamask with all parameter correct is not included in block in private network.

Comment: Can you give more details about your private network ? Are you mining on this network, what client do you use, etc..

Comment: Try switching to other mainnet and back again to your private network, some apps will not switch properly so the tx nonce is not set properly. If that fails you can try restarting your browser.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to running multiple network and working with same account.
There is no any issue with that but you must reset account before switching to other network. Metamask maitain nonce for account after executing first transaction.